# Stage loses fill (gradient) after simply creating a new control

Tags: javafx

I have reduced my recreate of this to the following.  The line where a `ToggleButton` is instantiated causes my stage to lose its fill color; it goes white. I am just getting started with JavaFX, so please let me know if I'm doing something I shouldn't, here.  This is using jre1.8.0_92 with Eclipse Neon (jfx8_2.3.0 plugin) on Windows 7 sp1.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(args.length > 0) { 
            String s = args[0].toLowerCase();
            if(s.equals("full"))
                    Machine.isFullScreen = true;
        }
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Machine.startMachine(primaryStage);
    } 
}

public class Machine {

    static boolean isFullScreen = false;
    static Rectangle2D screenRect, backRect;
    static Stage backStage;
    static Scene backScene;
    static Pane backPane;

    private Machine() {}

    static public void startMachine(Stage primaryStage) {

        // backscreen
        startScene(primaryStage);

        // This line causes the fill to be lost
        ToggleButton foo = new ToggleButton("hi");
    }

    static private void startScene(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Stage
        backStage = primaryStage;
        backStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        backStage.setFullScreen(isFullScreen);
        screenRect = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        if(!isFullScreen) {
            int w = 1000, h = 500, t = 20;
            backStage.setWidth(w);
            backStage.setHeight(h);
            backStage.setX((screenRect.getWidth() - w)/2);
            backStage.setY(t);
        }
        backRect = new Rectangle2D(backStage.getX(), backStage.getY(),
                backStage.getWidth(), backStage.getHeight());

        // Scene
        backScene = new Scene(backPane = new Pane());
        // backScene.getStylesheets().add(Machine.class.getResource("mainStyle.css").toExternalForm());
        // backScene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #CCFF99;");
        backScene.setFill(new LinearGradient(0,0,1,1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
            new Stop[]{
                    new Stop(0,Color.web("#4977A3")),
                    new Stop(0.5, Color.web("#B0C6DA")),
                    new Stop(1,Color.web("#9CB6CF")), } )); 
        // Logo
        Text logo = new Text("AMT");
        logo.setFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);
        Font font = Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 96);
        logo.setFont(font);
        logo.setX(100);
        logo.setY(150);
        backPane.getChildren().add(logo);
        backStage.setScene(backScene);
        backStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        backStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`setFill()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setFill-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-) API suggests that this may be a stylesheet effect. The default stylesheet is installed statically when the first `Control` is instantiated. If that stylesheet is [`Modena`](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/), "the default fill is set to be a light gray color." Instead of `backScene.setFill()`, try `backPane.setBackground()`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049996/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616109/230513).

[image]

```
// Scene
backPane = new Pane();
backScene = new Scene(backPane);
LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(
    0, 0, 1, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
    new Stop(0, Color.web("#4977A3")),
    new Stop(0.5, Color.web("#B0C6DA")),
    new Stop(1, Color.web("#9CB6CF")));
backPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
    linearGradient, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
```

As an aside, note that the [*varargs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) constructor parameter of [`LinearGradient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html#LinearGradient-double-double-double-double-boolean-javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod-javafx.scene.paint.Stop...-) allows you to add instances of `Stop` directly, without creating a new array.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Is there a logical reason why the Scene fill went away (or would)?  Because I hadn't yet put the button in any Scene (in this example).  Did it go into the overall set of nodes or something?

Comment: @MarkMeyers: I'm not sure, but the [`setFill()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setFill-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-) API suggests a stylesheet effect.